# Primary components of lexical-syntactical analysis

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

What is lexical-syntactical analysis as it applies to Biblical hermeneutics? What are the primary steps involved in a lexical-syntactical analysis of a Biblical passage?

Answer (score 7):

> Lexical-syntactical analysis is the study of the meaning of individual words (lexicology) and the way those words are combined (syntax) in order to determine more accurately the author’s intended meaning.
>   Virkler & Ayayo, *Hermeneutics: Principles and processes of Biblical interpretation*, p. 98 (2nd ed. 2007).

Essentially, it's looking at the individual words (*Lexical*) and their usage (*Syntactical*) in order to determine the original meaning (*Analysis*).

The different components of lexical-syntactical analysis, per [here](http://infinisis.com/templates/System/details.asp?id=23753&PID=611407) are:

- Identify the general literary form
- Reconstruct the development of the author's theme and how a passage fits into the context
- Identify the natural divisions of the text
- Identify the connecting words within paragraphs and sentences
- Identify points of comparison, contrast and conclusion
- Determine what the individual words mean
- Analyze the relationship between words (syntax)
- Summarize your results into an easily understood synopsis that clearly conveys the author's meaning

A (possibly dramatic) simplification of this would be:

- Determine the meaning of each word (Lexicon)
- Examine the relationship between the words (Syntax)
- Analyze the words in the context of the sentence.

Interestingly, it seems to be used frequently for programming languages as well.

Comment: You just can't get away from programming at SE, even when talking about hermeneutics :) Thanks for the answer!